# How do I get Thunderbird and Ubuntu (WUBI) and Windows to share a profile?

Tags: windows-7, xubuntu, wubi, thunderbird

I have a friend who is running Xubuntu 12.04 through WUBI.  They have Thunderbird installed in both Xubuntu and Windows and a single IMAP account set up in both (same IMAP account).

The problem is that the email provider only allows 20MB of storage. So the user need to get the message off of the IMAP server and into a local folder. However, he wants to be able to have access to those local folders in both Windows and Xubuntu. I'm sure there's away for Thunderbird to share access to these folders but I'm not sure how. Do I just need to set his local folders in Ubuntu to point to the folder in Windows or is it more complicated?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you should be able to share whole profile between Windows and Xubuntu.
In order to do that you may do following things:

**Move the profile** from Thunderbird on Xubuntu to a place that you can easily access both from Windows and Xubuntu. (for instance your Windows system partition). You have to find where you profile is actually stored. The profile folder should be located at:

```
home/your_username/.thunderbird/xxxxxxxxxx.default
```

Obviously replace your_username with your username ;)
In place of 'xxxxxxxxxx' you'll see some randomly looking signs. It varies for each profile. Copy the whole folder to place explained before.

Now you have to **set access** to the moved profile from Xubuntu's Thunderbird. Run thunderbird's **profile manager**:

```
thunderbird --profilemanager
```

Create Profile > Next > Choose folder, and choose folder path to where did you copy your profile.

---

Now the second part - Windows. Simply open properties of your shortcut to Thunderbird, and **in path add following**:

```
-profile "C:\xxxxxxxxx"
```

Where you have to add path to the previously copied profile.
Whole path should look something like:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe" -profile "C:\xxxxxxxxxxx"
```

---

Keep me updated if the solution works and/or any problems occured. Good luck.